# Test POST request with multipartfile with Spring

Tags: java, spring, testing, controller, multipartfile

I have a controller sending post requests which is working well and communicating with the client correctly. However, I am unable to test it with in JUnit.
The controller receives a multipartfile, along with 2 boolean parameters (that are required), and accept only "application/xls" as content type.
To do the test I am mocking the multipartfile and the parameters. However, when I do it this way, I get the following error : `handler.RestExceptionHandler: Exception caught. Wrong file type;\n Import .xls or .xlsx file` (from my exception handler).

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/file",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> parseMultipartFile(
            @RequestParam MultipartFile multipartFile,
            @RequestParam boolean hasOnlyOneSheet,
            @RequestParam boolean hasBorders) throws IOException {

        String fileContentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
        if (mimeType.contains(fileContentType)) {

            InputStream parsedFile = multipartFileToHtmlService.multipartFileToHtml(multipartFile, hasOnlyOneSheet, hasBorders);
            InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(parsedFile);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(inputStreamResource);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedImportMediaTypeException("Wrong file type;\n Import .xls or .xlsx file");
        }
    }
```

and here is my test:

```java
@WebMvcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class HtmlExporterControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    MultipartFileToHtmlService multipartFileToHtmlService;

    @MockBean
    HtmlToHtmlServiceFactory htmlToHtmlServiceFactory;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
   public void parseMultipartFile_Should_Return_Ok() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(
                "multipartFile",
                "test.xls",
                "application/x-xls",
                "Hello World!".getBytes());

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/file")
                .file("multipartFile", mockMultipartFile.getBytes())
                .param("hasOnlyOneSheet", "true")
                .param("hasBorders", "true"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

To avoid this issue, I tried to pass the boolean values as new multipart/form-data like so:

```java
    @Test
   public void parseMultipartFile_Should_Return_Ok() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(
                "multipartFile",
                "test.xls",
                "application/x-xls",
                "Hello World!".getBytes());

        MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile1 = new MockMultipartFile(
                "hasBorders",
                "",
                "",
                "true".getBytes());

        MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile2 = new MockMultipartFile(
                "hasOnlyOneSheet",
                "",
                "",
                "true".getBytes());

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/file")
                .file("multipartFile", mockMultipartFile.getBytes())
                .file("hasOnlyOneSheet", mockMultipartFile1.getBytes())
                .file("hasBorders", mockMultipartFile2.getBytes()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

But then, I get the following error `Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile' to required type 'boolean';`

Once again, the request is working, i can also do it on [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), here is the curl request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/file' \
--form 'multipartFile=@/MyPath/test.xlsx' \
--form 'hasBorders=true' \
--form 'hasOnlyOneSheet=true'
```

Comment: Stacktrace of the exception would help. BTW there's no point in passing boolean values as a MultipartFile.

Comment: The exception is a wrong File Type Exception, it should be only "application/xls" type (but it should be the case in my test case). If I completely remove the exception handler I get ` Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream must not be null`

Comment: Could you update the question with a complete stack trace for your initial test? Also, provide a sample test.xlsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps someone else, I solved it by adding a real excel sheet:

```
@WebMvcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class HtmlExporterControllerTest {

@MockBean
MultipartFileToHtmlService multipartFileToHtmlService;

@MockBean
HtmlToHtmlServiceFactory htmlToHtmlServiceFactory;

@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void parseMultipartFile_Should_Return_Ok() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(
            "multipartFile",
            "test.xls",
            "application/x-xls",
            new ClassPathResource("test.xls").getInputStream());

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/file")
            .file(mockMultipartFile)
            .param("hasOnlyOneSheet", "true")
            .param("hasBorders", "true"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```